# How to access certain part of an XML?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-2.0

Good day!

How can I access this part of XML and print the element name?
Please refer to the image below.

[image]

I'm now not able to progress with the following codes:

```
    XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();         
                XmlNode xmlnode;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Files\20120604\Data_120604-062516_003.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                xmldoc.Load(fs);


//MessageBox.Show("YUMDMMATMAS05");
```

Comment: Read [ask]. What did you try? did you read the documentation ? Which error do you get ? What is 42?

Comment: This is what I have done so far and not able to progress on it: `XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();                          XmlNode xmlnode;                 FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Files\20120604\Data_120604-062516_003.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);                 xmldoc.Load(fs); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the behavior you want is to get the root node, then you can get it with `xmldoc.DocumentElement`.

You can get the name of any XMLElement using the Name property.

Comment: sorry, but my scenario is I have many XML files and I have to know the name of the very first element for each xml.. For example, XML1 has YUMDMMATMAS05 and XML2 has YUMDMMATMAS05 for the first element. I have no knowldge of the name of the first element

Comment: @yonan2236 My solution does not require that you know the name of the first element. I'm saying that you access the first element's name by using xmldoc.DocumentElement.Name in your code above after you call xmldoc.Load().

Comment: sorry I did not got it right away, but it is working for me. Thanks Fur

Comment: @yonan2236 No problem. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

```
Pattern = @"\?>\s*?<(?<Name>.*?)>.*?</(1)>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the rest of the document then don't read the entire thing into the memory with `XmlDataDocument` (obsolete btw) or `XmlDocument`, but use `XmlReader` insted (`XmlTextReader` is also kind of obsolete):

```
using(var reader = XmlReader.Create(new FileStream(@"D:\Files\20120604\Data_120604-062516_003.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), new XmlReaderSettings { CloseInput = true, DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore, IgnoreComments = true, IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true, IgnoreWhitespace = true }))
            {
                XmlNodeType nt;
                do
                {
                    nt = reader.MoveToContent();
                    if(nt == XmlNodeType.Element) {
                        MessageBox.Show(nt.Name);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                while(nt != XmlNodeType.None)
            }
```